# Google sheet API V4 append values formatting issue?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

There is a problem in google sheet api v4. My application first add formatted heading row (Image1) to the user sheet via of sheet batchUpdate EHD point .

[image: Image1]

When my application start appending values (start from A1 or A2) into the sheet the new appended rows are also formatted like the first row (Image2) [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbUJp.png)

When i start appending from A3 (leave row2 empty) then it work fine (Image3)

[image: Image3]

This is API Endpoint:

`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheet.id}/values/${sheet.gridName}!A1:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&insertDataOption=INSERT_ROWS`

My Question is why google sheet append values function with insert_rows parameter copy the design(formatting) of the above row (last row after insert the new one) and how to solve this?

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: About `insertDataOption=OVERWRITES work fine but when user send two request in very short time it actually overwrite last row and append only one row.`, I cannot know your situation. In this case, the Sheets API is used in a loop? Or, Sheets API is used with multiple users, simultaneously? If it's the former, can you provide your current script for replicating the issue?